# Visual Basic 2008 | How to Check only One MenuStrip Item at a Time

Tags: vb.net

Good morning everyone!

I have a Menustrip in Visual Basic 2008.

My question is how do I check only one menu item at a time?

Lets assumed I have a **MenuScript** that is titled Fruits.

When you click on Fruits, you get a drop down of four fruits.

**Apples, Orange, Bananas and Mango.**

If you click on a fruit there is a check mark indicating that item is either active or that the item was click. This is called **CheckOnClick**.

The problem is I only need the check mark on one item at a time. So if I check Apples and decide to check orange, then Apples should **uncheck** and Orange should have the check mark.

Currently, if I check apples and check orange, both items will have check marks.

I need to have only one item check at a time.

I do not have access to my code at the moment, so please bear with me.

Thanks every one!

Novice

Answer (score 0):

Link to MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.checked.aspx

Alternatively:

On menu item click event - parse through all menu items and set selected property = false.   set selected property = true for selected menu item.

hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

' First set all to false.

```
for each item in toolstripitem.dropdownitems
   item.checked = False
next
```

' Then check what you want.

```
toolstriptemcolor1.checked = true
```